# Как поставить глагол "победить" в 1 л. буд. вр. (я побе...)?

Tags: грамотная-речь, склонение, глаголы

Видеть-я увижу, победить-я ....?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Провокационный" вопрос,это НЕДОСТАТОЧНЫЙ глагол, у которого нет простой формы 1 лица из-за неблагозвучия, можно сказать только "я одержу победу" или что-то похожее:
[Недостаточные глаголы](http://language.mypage.ru/nedostatochnie_glagoli.html)